# How to load images in order with unveil.js

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using unveil.js to load a site more quickly.

I have a white div that blocks the content, which I want to disappear after the first images have loaded.

I though I could just count the images, but I realize that some of the latter ones could just load first (which normally happens because there is a threshold parameter which loads the ones that follow on the scroll).

Could someone help me with a smart way to do this?

Here's my code and the crappy solution:

```
$("img").unveil(2000, function() {
    $(this).load(function(){
    if(imageCount >= 4){
        $(".white-cover").fadeOut("slow");
        imageCount = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since unveil changes the src attribute, you can use jQuery to listen to an attribute change which indicate that an image has been replaced.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selected-date-range").change(function(){
     alert( $("#selected-date-range").attr("value") );
  });
});
```

Comment: But if I'm not mistaken, this solution doesn't take care of checking that it's the first images right? For example, the first three. The problem I have is that since some images that are smaller in size, load before the first ones.

Answer (score -1):

In case I understand your problem correctly, I would use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // all images are loaded
}
```

Does this help you?